# How to validate sub classes that were deserilaized with Jackson polymorpic deserialization

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation

I have a POIPage class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = POIText.class, name = "text"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = POIImage.class, name = "image"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = POITable.class, name = "table"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = POIVideo.class, name = "video"),
})
@Data
public abstract class POIPage {
    abstract public void accept(PageVisitor pageVisitor) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException;
}
```

And POIText is:

```
@Data
public class POIText extends POIPage {
    // Spring doesn't control here
    @NotBlank
    private String description;

    @Override
    public void accept(PageVisitor pageVisitor) {
        pageVisitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

i use it like this:

```
@Data
public class PresentationPage {
    private ELayout layout;
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    private String title;

    // this line
    List<@Valid POIPage> poiPages;
}
```

While validation takes place in POIPage, it does not happen in POIText. How can i solve this situation ? Thank you...

Comment: I feel there's no a full example of yours such as I can provide you with a full answer, but, I think you need to try to include the `type` property somehow (in the request payload, if any, for example) to indicate whether the object is a `POIText` or any other type. In the past I've created a *demo* to demonstrate this usage. You can see it here: https://github.com/lealceldeiro/abstractmapping

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I don't have a problem with jackson (type conversion).  Just @NotBlank annotation  doesnt work

Comment: At runtime, what type of objects are in the `poiPages`? is there any `POIText` instance? ... adding a full example of what you're doing would help us to help you :): request example, controller handling the request, etc.

Comment: Thank you :) mb, just wrong request object. Problem solved.

Comment: @salagoz Could you please explain how did you solve the problem?